# Get coordinates on page load

Tags: javascript

I have an event listener to grab the cursors coordinates relative to the canvas it is positioned over that fires on mousemove. How can I alter this so it also provides the coordinates on page load, before the mouse has been moved? I've tried, but the coordinates display `undefined`. Have a look:

```
<body onload="start()">
<script>
function start(){
                Coords.start();
            }

var Coords = {
                canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
                start : function() {
                    this.canvas.width = 600;
                    this.canvas.height = 350;
                    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
                    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);

                    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", getRelativeCoords, false);

                    getRelativeCoords(Coords.canvas); //my attempt at grabbing coords on page load. this displays 'underfined' 
                },

            }

function getRelativeCoords(event) {
                document.getElementById("coordinates").innerHTML = "x: " + event.offsetX + " y: " + event.offsetY;
            }
</script>
<p id="coordinates"></p>
</body>
```

I have a span that displays the coordiantes.

I'm not at all familiar with javascript (started learning a few days ago), so I would really appreciate an explanation. Thanks

Comment: According to this example (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_createelement) i am assuming that you need to append created element. Right not CANVAS is not present in DOM.

Comment: Oops... must of cut that line out when formatting the code for the question. You'll see I re-added it. This doesn't work, either. @SkyWookie

Comment: document.getElementById("coordinates") returns undefined. Also, you have not invoked Coords.start() any where.

Comment: I didn't choose to include that code. It is now. @alireza